# Is there faster way to create a list of (0,1) combination in python?

Tags: python

I want create a list with ones insert in combination place of zeros as following:

```
l = [(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
     (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
     (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
     (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
     (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
     (0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
     (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
     (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
     (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
     (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
     (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
     (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
     (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
     (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
     (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

I can construct the list by using

```
[e for e in itertools.product(range(2), repeat=6) if sum(e)==2]
```

However, when parameter of `repeat` gets larger as 20, the code is very time consuming.

I thought it might be the problem of building up intermediate results in memory?
I want to know is there any better way to create the list I need.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems fine to me. You might simply have a large object there.

Comment: Yes, this is going to get increasingly slower since your method generates all possible binary sequences and then picks out the ones with two 1s. You're better off constructing the sequences directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-recursive way might work better at large N, and might be a little easier to understand -- we just choose k bits to activate.

```
import itertools

def bits_on(n, k):
    for which_on in itertools.combinations(range(n), k):
        out = [0]*n
        for index in which_on:
            out[index] = 1
        yield tuple(out)
```

which gives me

```
In [43]: list(bits_on(6, 2))
Out[43]: 
[(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)]
```

and

```
In [46]: %time len(list(bits_on(200,2)))
CPU times: user 132 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 132 ms
Wall time: 131 ms
Out[46]: 19900

In [47]: %time len(list(choose(200,2)))
CPU times: user 9.4 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 9.4 s
Wall time: 9.4 s
Out[47]: 19900

In [48]: set(bits_on(200,2)) == set(choose(200,2))
Out[48]: True
```

Comment: If you're going to use itertools you can just do something like `list(set(itertools.permutations([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])))`

Comment: Nice. You can also generate them in lexicographic order if you do the opposite: choose the `n - k` bits to _deactivate_.

Comment: @pvg: that would be very inefficient.. for me it takes almost a second just to do `list(set(itertools.permutations([0]*8+[1]*2)))`.

Comment: @DSM sure but it's as short and even slower than the original!

Answer (score 6):

The following function returns a list of all `n`-tuples with `k` ones.  It works in a split second for `choose(50,2)`, for example:

```
def choose(n, k):
    if n < k or k < 0:
        return []
    elif n == 0:
        return [()]
    return \
        [(0,) + r for r in choose(n-1, k)] + \
        [(1,) + r for r in choose(n-1, k-1)]
```

The following is the output of `choose(6,2)`:

```
>>> choose(6,2)
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), 
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), 
 (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
 (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), 
 (0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
 (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
 (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
 (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
 (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
 (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
 (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

This is identical to the example in the question.